# The order of the antipode in a Hopf algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, hopf-algebras

As a result of Radford, any finite-dimensional Hopf algebra an antipode of finite order.

My question: How can we classify all finite-dimensional Hopf algebras whose antipode is identity?

Here are some examples: $kG$, group algebra with elements of $G$ having order at most 2.

Comment: I'm still waking up but I think such algebras are always both commutative and cocommutative, since the identity now has to be an anti-isomorphism, severely limiting your options.

Comment: Thank you.I have solved this question.Since，it's commutative，then we can prove it is isomorphi s m of the dual of group algebra. Then we can prove this group is the direct product of Z2（cyclic group with two elements）.

Comment: Yeah, the group algebra of $Z/2$ is basically your only option in characteristic different from $2$. In characteristic $2$ you have a couple options though.